# Modificar url dinámica en wordpress

Tags: .htaccess, url

Tengo una web en la que inserto códico mediante sort-codes para trabajar creando mi contenido propio mediante consultas y creando enlaces dinámicos de tipo https://www.joventutartistica.com/detall-espectacle-cartellera/?Num_Espectacle=110
Al intentar crear botones de compartir evidentemente tengo problemas con esas urls.
La idea sería conseguir mediante modificación del HTACCESS que esas urls no deseadas se convirtieran en amigables.
De esta manera https://www.joventutartistica.com/detall-espectacle-cartellera/?Num_Espectacle=110 pasaria a ser https://www.joventutartistica.com/detall-espectacle-cartellera/110 con lo que el sistema seguiria buscan por la primera url pero se veria la segunda.
Mi modificación del htaccess fracasó. el código insertado en htacess es:
RewriteRule ^detall-espectacle-cartellera/([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)$ detall-espectacle-cartellera/?Num_Espectacle=$1
Pero no me ha funcionado.
Qué es lo que hago mal? Hay alguna otra solución al tema de las urls dinámicas.
Gracias de antemano

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.